# Converting from Int to String Swift 2.2

Tags: swift

Dears

I have this case where chatId is a property of type Int

```
let StringMessage = String(self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)
```

When I debug I find that *StringMessage* is returning **Optional**(15) Which means it is unwrapped. But at the same time XCode does not allow me to put any bangs (!) to unwrap it. So I am stuck with Unwrapped Variable. I know its noob question but it I really cant get it. Your help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Add nil coalescing operator `?? 0` Or use if let or guard

Comment: Are you sure Xcode doesn't let you use bangs to unwrap? I find that odd. Not that you should use them (use guard-let-else instead), but it is strange that you don't have the option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want the default value to be.

Assuming you want the default value to be an empty string (""), You could create a function or a method to handle it.

```
func stringFromChatId(chatId: Int?) -> String {
    if let chatId = chatId {
        return String(chatId)
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}

let stringMessage = stringFromChatId(self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)
```

Or you could handle it with a closure.

```
let stringMessage = { $0 != nil ? String($0!) : "" }(self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)
```

If you don't mind crashing if `self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId` is `nil`, then you should be able to directly unwrap it.

```
let StringMessage = String((self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)!)
```

or with a closure

```
let stringMessage = { String($0!) }(self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)
```

---

**Update**

Assuming chatId is an `Int` and not an `Optional<Int>` (AKA `Int?`) I missed the most obvious unwrap answer. Sorry, I was tired last night.

```
let StringMessage = String(self.listingChat!.messages.last!.chatId)
```

Force unwrap all the optionals along the way.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But can you please explain to me why self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId returns unwrapped Value " But in Int" But when I call String((self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)!) I must unwrap it **Before** Converting it to String. I can get it if the unwrapping is after conversion. But what really can't get is why is it before conversion

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat `self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId` returns an `Optional<Int>`. It is not unwrapped.

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat I added a new answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support :) People like you make Stackoverflow great. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Optionals have a very nice method called `map` (unrelated to `map` for Arrays) which returns `nil` if the variable is `nil`, otherwise it calls a function on the (non-nil) value. Combined with a guard-let, you get very concise code. (I've changed the case of `stringMessage` because variables should begin with a lower-case letter.)

```
guard let stringMessage = self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId.map { String($0) } else {
    // Do failure
}

// Success. stringMessage is of type String, not String?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

```
let StringMessage = String(self.listingChat?.messages.last?.chatId)!
```